# Jetty MDC handler doesn't provide contextPath

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

Jetty `9.3.8.v20160314` running on AWS EC2 Linux machine with Java `1.8.0_51` has two web apps under two different dir+context.xml - `webapps/app1` and `webapps/app2` with an empty `webapps/ROOT` directory.

I'm trying to get each webapp to have a separate log with contextPath in its name.

Each app has the following `webapps/appX.xml` context defined -

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/appX</Set>
  <Set name="war">
    <SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/appX
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

Followed [Example: Centralized Logging with Logback](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/example-logging-logback-centralized.html) and installed webapp-logging module, app is using slf4j Logger and `resources/logback.xml` is -

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %t %c{0} [%p] %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator>
      <key>contextPath</key>
      <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
      <appender name="FILE-${contextPath}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${jetty.home}/logs/${contextPath}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
          <!-- daily rollover -->
          <fileNamePattern>${contextPath}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

          <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
          <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
          <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
          <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %t %c{0} [%p] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <append>true</append>
      </appender>
    </sift>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="SIFT"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

But it all goes to `unknown.log`. Using `servername` instead works well and creates separate file for each domain being used to access the server.

So it would seem that `contextPath` isn't properly assigned by `ContextLogHandler`.

Why is it empty?